# refer to bash variable or bash expression in xmlstarlet (xpath) expression

Tags: xml, bash, xpath, xmlstarlet

I want to match a date in an xml attribute. I've tried the following command:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'string(//*[local-name()="***"][@date="$(date +'%d %b %y')"]/@...)' file.xml
```

I've also tried to replace the bash expression with a bash variable. I've used single and double quotes, normal and curly parentheses, and no dice.

Comment: Show exactly what you tried. Double quotes should work.

Comment: @choroba, correction: Double quotes should work **if** you close your single quotes first, which the OP isn't doing.

Comment: Can you show the other commands you have tried, along with the error messaged for each command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close your single quotes before opening double quotes; otherwise, the single-quotes quote the double quotes, so they have no effect.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v \
  'string(//*[local-name()="***"][@date="'"$(date +'%b %d $y')"'"]/@...)' file.xml

# 'single-quoted content here"'"double-quoted content here"'"single-quoted content here'
# |                          ^|                            |^                          |
# |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||                            |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

The `"`s with `^` characters under them as LITERAL: They're escaped by the single-quotes surrounding them, and thus become part of the string passed to xmlstarlet. The other `"`, not surrounded by `'`, are syntactic: They're directives to the shell that contents of the `$(date)` expansion are not to be word-split or glob-expanded. (The pipes are showing which parts of the string are single-quoted, with the caveat that the single-quotes on the end are syntactic rather than literal, and thus not actually quoted themselves).

It may be easier to look at the differently-quoted substrings the shell is concatenating into a single argument-list element:

- `'string(//*[local-name()="***"][@date="'` - Single-quoted, *including* the literal `"` at the end.
- `"$(date +'%b %d $y')"` - Double-quoted.
- `'"]/@...)'` - Single-quoted, *including* the literal `"` at the beginning.

Comment: yep, there's the issue.

Comment: i'm a bit confused, the double-quotes with `^` characters under them surround the single-quotes, not vice versa.

Comment: Why does the bash expression need to be surrounded with double-quotes again? When I try `...@date='"$(date +'%b %d %y')"'`, I get an invalid predicate, and see that the date has been properly expanded. What is passed to xmlstarlet exactly?

Comment: @cfye14, look at it as three separate strings, the way I split it out later: The single-quotes *are* in fact the ones surrounding the double-quotes, in the first and third of those substrings.

Comment: @cfye14, if you want to see the *exact* string passed to xmlstarlet, use `printf '%s\n' 'string(//*[local-name()="***"][@date="'"$(date +'%b %d $y')"'"]/@...)'`.

Comment: @cfye14, ...I've expanded the diagram to make it more clear how the single-quotes are quoting the double-quotes.

Comment: BTW, why the messing around with `local-name()`? Do you not know the namespace applicable to the elements being matched? In general, queries using it are going to be less efficient than ones that hardcode the element name, explicitly specifying a namespace if necessary.

Comment: re: namespaces, good q, I had just quickly copied something from elsewhere and repurposed it. Indeed I can change that ...